# Where to store drl files in a WAR file?

Tags: drools

I have it under WEB-INF\classes\com\abc\rules directory currently.  Is that correct?

My rules contain sensitive company logic so I don't want people be able to read the files.  Ideally I want to encrypt them in the WAR files but I heard it's not doable with rules (drl) files.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First: people that don't know what your RBS does aren't likely to use it. Usually it is the user (customer) who defines what the rules should do, or needs to know what they do before they use the system. Hiding the rules from the users is akin to invite them to ask the Delphian oracle: they'll get an answer all right - but is it the right one?

That said, you can serialize a KieBase and even a KieSession, so you don't need to distribute DRL text. But (as so often) s.o. determined to unravel the object contents will still be able to learn the tricks - at a price - if they can get at the ObjectStream.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of any resources that show how to serialize KieBase or KieSession and read it back so I don't have to include the DRL files?